CSS selector: value of table cell inside a row that contains another table cell with value
Okay, so this is a bit convulted but bear with me.. If i have a DOM like this:
<table id="myId">
  <tr>
    <td>date1start - date1end</td>
    <td>not interesting</td>
    <td><a>link</a></td> <-- need this
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date2start - date2end</td>
    ...similar cells...
  ...multiple rows...
</table>

and i want to use CSS selector to get the A element inside a row that contains a TD with the text '- date1end' how would you go about it?
I'm thinking that I can do TABLE#myId TD[Text$='- date1end'] to locate the cell inside correct row, but how do I navigate to the 2nd cell to the right?

"I'm thinking that I can do TABLE#myId TD[Text$='- date1end']" - unless you are talking about something else than actual CSS in the browser - like the extended syntax of some DOM library or scraper - then no, you won't be able to do that. [foo$='bar'] is attribute selector syntax, but you are not dealing with an attribute here. The answer to Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text? is still "No" as of now.

Currently you need Javascript to find the element containing a specific text string.

Okay so under the hood this is power automate desktop with an html element action, but afaik the syntax is CSS3. so cannot do javascript. Not to bash anyone I just thought these tags would get responses from people with more experience in selectors

@C3roe Okay thanks. I need to think of some other magic
